# If $F(1)=11 $ and $F(n)=F(n/4)+7$. Prove that $F(n)= 7n+11$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, recurrence-relations

> Find a closed formula for the recurrence below. Then, prove by
>   induction that the formula found is correct.
>
> $$F(n) = \begin{cases} 11, & \mbox{if } n = 1 \\ F(n/4)+7, & \mbox{if }
>  n > 1 \end{cases}$$

Assume that $n = 4^{k} $ for $ k \geq 0$

```
(k, F(n)): (1,1)(2,3)(3,6)(4,10)(5,15)(6,21)(7,28)(8,36)
```

Closed formula: $$F(4^{n})
 = 7n+11$$

How to prove it by induction?

Comment: Title does not match claimed "Closed formula"

Comment: The information you are given is insufficient to determine $F(1/2)$.

Comment: Assume that $n = 4^{k} $ for $ k \geq 0$

Comment: I found the closed formula through Lagrange Interpolation

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assume $n=4^k$ for $k\geq0$. Note that $n=1$ $\iff$ $k=0$, and $n/4=4^{k-1}$. Now, re-write your recurrence as follows:
\begin{equation}
 F(4^k) =
   \begin{cases}
    11            ,& \text{if } \ k=0 \\
    F(4^{k-1})+7  ,& \text{if } \ k>0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Define an auxiliary recurrence $f(k)$, such as $f(k)=F(4^k)$ (hence $f(k-1)=F(4^{k-1})$), and substitute it in the recurrence from above:
\begin{equation}
 f(k) =
   \begin{cases}
    11        ,& \text{if } \ k=0 \\
    f(k-1)+7  ,& \text{if } \ k>0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Now, this $f(k)$ recurrence has a pretty well known method for solving it:

- First, solve **homogeneous equation** $f_h(k)-f_h(k-1)=0$

Try substituting $f_h(k)=cr^k$, for $c\neq0$, in the homogeneous equation $\Longrightarrow cr^k-cr^{k-1}=0$. Divide by $cr^{k-1}$, and you will have $r=1$. Hence $f_h(k)=c1^k \Longrightarrow f_h(k)=c$

- Second, solve **particular (non-homogeneous) equation** $f_p(k)-f_p(k-1)=7$

Because of having a constant in the RHS, you should try a constant as a particular solution. However, this choice will not be linearly independent with the $f_h(k)$ solution calculated before, because it is a constant too. So take $f_p(k)=ak$ for ensure linear independence between $f_h(k)$ and $f_p(k)$. Now substitute $f_p(k)$ in the non-homogeneous equation $\Longrightarrow ak-a(k-1)=7 \Longrightarrow ak-ak+a=7 \Longrightarrow a=7$. Hence $f_p(k)=7k$

- Third, the **general solution** for $f(k)$ will be the sum of both $f_h(k)$ and $f_p(k)$

Hence $f(k)=7k+c$. Now it's time to use the base-case value: $f(0)=11$ and $f(0)=7\cdot0+c=c$, so $c=11$, and the **closed formula** for $f(k)$ it is
\begin{equation}
 f(k)=7k+11
\end{equation}

Recall $n=4^k \iff k=\log_4(n)$, and $f(k)=F(4^k)$. Therefore, $f(k)=f(\log_4(n))=F(4^{\log_4(n)})=F(n)$, and the **closed formula** for $F(n)$ it is
\begin{equation}
 F(n)=7\cdot\log_4(n)+11
\end{equation}

Now, you are able to prove it by induction. I will do induction over $k$, since $f(k)=F(n)$.

- **Basis:** $k=0 \ \Longrightarrow f(0)=7\cdot0+11=11 \ \Longrightarrow$ correct
- **Induction hypothesis:** $f(k)=7k+11$
- **Goal:** $f(k+1)=7(k+1)+11$
- **Proof:** By definition, $f(k)=f(k-1)+7 \Longrightarrow f(k+1)=f(k)+7$. Now use induction hypothesis for $f(k)$, then $f(k+1)=7k+11+7 \Longrightarrow f(k+1)=7(k+1)+11$

$\blacksquare$